# Questions and Answers missing

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

List of my  questions and  my answers have disappeared in the new updated version today, though the data about how long I have been member, my location etc are intact. The reputation points have come down from 700 plus to 596.

Answer (score 2):

So far as I can tell, your questions and answers are still intact; note that only 5 of each are displayed on your profile [*summary*](https://mathoverflow.net/users/22878/p-vanchinathan), but you can view all of them by clicking through to the [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/users/22878/p-vanchinathan?tab=questions) and [answers](https://mathoverflow.net/users/22878/p-vanchinathan?tab=answers) tabs.

Your reputation dropped a bit - like most everyone's did - because [the reputation rules have changed a bit and is now recalculated continuously](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/11/has-there-been-a-recalculation-of-reputation) (so deleted posts don't count towards / against it). For details on the new reputation rules, see: https://mathoverflow.net/help/whats-reputation

Comment: Thanks. Yes, now they have reappeared magically!