# Can MO go back to +5 rep for questions? Should it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, mathoverflow-inc

In case you missed the news, [upvotes on questions now grant +10 reputation instead of +5](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?cb=1), and the change has been implemented retroactively (most if not all users have already had their reputation recalculated). This change was welcomed mostly neutrally or positively (who doesn't like free rep?) but I did hear some concerns from other users about where this may take us (mostly those who I know personally, but [this meta question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4385/30186) is very likely motivated by a similar concern (edit: that question is now deleted; it asked about the impact of the change on the number of questions posted)).

I am aware that while MathOverflow is part of Stack Exchange, there is a unique agreement between MO and SE (as described and linked [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/969/30186)). I admit I have not read the entirety of the agreement so I don't know exactly what it allows in regards to MO following different rules than other SE sites.

My questions are then this:

> Would it be possible, if the community and/or the moderation team on MO decide so, to revert this reputation change on this site?
>
> If there is such a possibility, should we take it?

**Opinion ahead:** I am personally not a fan of the change. While I understand where the SE are coming from introducing it, arguing that asking a good question is an art in itself, I feel like it is not as true on this website as it is elsewhere. While there are of course some great questions there (like [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/195353/30186)), I do still believe that writing a good question is generally not as much of a demanding task as coming up with a good answer, the latter often requiring more insight and sheer work, and they should be rewarded accordingly. There are of course people who disagree with me on this stand (this was the [most upvoted feature request](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/1054/30186)), but I know people who agree, and I would like to put this to a discussion.

Comment: Since MO originated from SE1.0 software, it used to be 10 points for questions (and also -1 for downvoting questions). When MO joined SE2.0 it was changed back. So if anything, we're not changing as much as going back. And if you read the announcement, that is also how SE views this change.

Comment: If I remember right, lots of people wanted MO to opt out of the switch to +5 in the first place.

Comment: In my opinion, questions and answers are basically of equal importance: There will be no answers without questions and without a prospect for an answer or helpful information, there would be no questions. I welcome the switch back to 10 points for questions.

Comment: Adding the tag feature-request, because we need input from the SE team to answer the first part of this question, and (as far as I understand) they actively track only meta questions tagged feature-request or bug, not those tagged discussion.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni For what is worth (and I do realize this is not an authoritative answer) the possibility of reverting this change are essentially zero (and in my personal opinion I consider it a good thing: the reverse change was essentially a failed policy and there's no reason to keep legacy conventions forever just because people got used to them).

Comment: I actually don't think it makes much difference either way.

Answer (score 59):

Let me answer from the perspective of someone who is not a mathematician but follows this community for certain topics of interest.

This is a community of professional mathematicians where, indeed, questions are usually very well researched and posed, and there's virtually no risk of rewarding homework dump. So, if there's a community in which questions' upvotes really deserve the same value of answers' upvotes is this one.

Answer (score 19):

I received a huge reputation boost from this change, but I still think that answering a question still takes much more effort than writing well-posed questions. Coming up with a good mathematical question is rather easy, one usually is in a specific situation, wants to draw a certain conclusion, so one adds a couple of assumptions that make obvious counterexamples disappear, and if one does not find a proof within a couple of hours, it might be a good question.

Answering a question still takes much more effort and should be rewarded higher in my opinion.

Comment: I think this might vary between people. I got a little boost, but nothing to write home about, and indeed for me answering questions is much, much easier than asking them.

Answer (score 15):

I don't have a strong opinion on this subject, but insofar as I have one, it is this: **Changing the rules is more trouble than it's worth.**  I lost points back when +10 was downgraded to +5, and I gained points when the +5 was upgraded to +10, and in both cases I was mostly annoyed that the rules had been changed for (what I perceived as) no good reason.  So I would oppose yet another change.

Although I agree with Noah Snyder's warning not to treat MO like a game, there is one analogy that I would like to draw.  Inexperienced game designers often think that a well-established game can be "improved" by tinkering with the rules.  They usually underestimate the value of having a stable rule-set, and overestimate the beneficial impact that the rule change will have.  A good example of this IMO is chess. Changing the rule that capturing the king wins the game, to the rule that  checkmate wins the game (and moving into check is illegal) accomplished nothing other than to make the game harder to teach, and make the stalemate rule seem bizarre.  **If it ain't broke, don't fix it.** Neither +5 nor +10 for questions is "broken" IMO, so I'm not in favor of fixing it.

Answer (score 7):

I am not against the change, but I am strongly against the change being implemented **retroactively**.  I felt the same way when question upvotes were changed from 10 points to 5 points retroactively, and many users lost a significant amount of points.  I personally consider reputation points as glorified video game points, but I agree with Timothy Chow that part of the appeal of a video game is that it has a stable rule set.

Of course, video game rules are arbitrary, but we all agree to play by the same rules. The rules may be changed, but there should be a good reason for the change, and the community should be consulted.  Can the MO moderators at least confirm that they were notified of the potential change?  Now, even if the community agrees to a rule change, it is absurd to implement that rule change retroactively.  That would be like the National Basketball Association retroactively awarding 3 points for every 3-point basket before the 3-point line was introduced.

Comment: Here is a link to a post on [meta.se] (which I [already mentioned in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2019/11/16)) that is - to some extent - related to the issue that the change was retroactive: [Today's change has retroactively changed the meaning of our past votes. Should we be able to change them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338155) (Maybe also: [What to do concretely about the new “Every question asker gets more reputation retroactively, no questions asked” (pun not intended)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338135).)

Comment: Regarding the issue that community should have been consulted - see: [New Reputation Calculation - was the community asked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338113) Regarding the question whether the mods were notified - see the [response from Todd Trimble](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52552859#52552859) and the [clarification added by Denis Nardin](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52558612#52558612) in chat.

Comment: I usually take games very seriously, but MO is one where I think it’s a terrible idea to take the game seriously.  We should be taking our job as professional mathematicians seriously, and that means not treating MO purely as a video game.

Comment: Dear Tony, it was also implemented retroactively when MO moved from +10 to questions to +5 to questions some years ago (6?7?)

Comment: @GilKalai It was in June 2013: [Has there been a recalculation of reputation?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/11) and [How did I lose all my reputation points?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/557) A side-effect of MO joining the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @NoahSnyder I edited my answer to better convey what I meant.

Comment: @GilKalai Hi Gil!  Yes, I was aware of that, and was against the retroactive change back then too.  Congratulations on getting your points back though!

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I benefited **a lot** from this change, as I ask a lot of questions.

Overall I think it is fair to have upvotes for both questions and answers count the same, although it will - even for a well-posed reseach-level question - require more effort in average to answer it, than to ask it.

Here's another approach: Why don't we give more reputation for the poster of an answer that gets accepted by the one who asked the question, than we do today? (I.e., instead of putting more weight to answer upvoted, put more emphasis to acceptance.)

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you are advocating more points for the poster who accepts an answer, or for the poster whose answer is accepted (or both?).

Comment: Right, sorry for the ambiguous post. I argue for more points for the poster who wrote the accepted answer. Tried to make it more clear with an edit.

Answer (score -3):

Good questions are valuable but at the same time, I've always felt Stack Overflow's gamification features are among its least appealing features and I'd rather that MO just get rid of all those scores altogether.

For a long time I posted with no account at all and still do sometimes, but finally broke down and enrolled one because I wanted to use the comments feature, which requires a certain score. That requirement is also dumb imho.  Good questions, answers, and comments are able to stand on their own.

Comment: [meta.se]: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173) (Even the spam in posts is removed on MO slower than on sites with larger userbase. New comments are more difficult to spot, so removing the limit to comment would very likely lead to more spam.) I will add a reminder about the way to deal with spam in posts: [What should I do when I see a spam post on MO?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4259)

Comment: New comments being more difficult to spot could be fixed with a software patch, allowing viewing the most recent comments.

Comment: I highly doubt that it would help that much. Here is example from today - [a spam post](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/211490) for which it took more than 30 minutes on the site before it got removed. If the MO users are inactive in dealing with spam in posts (either they don't care or they simply do not know how to deal with spam posts), it's overly optimistic to think that they will actively be checking also comments for spam.

Comment: BTW it seems that various users have created some ways of getting to recent comments (probably from the API). For example, you can get the most recent comments for a particular site here: https://charcoal-se.org/blaze/ (Which I found from an answer here: [Is it possible to view all recent comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272787)) And it seems that there are also various chatbots that collect comments as they appear on a site, like [this one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/433480/meta-stalker?tab=recent).

Comment: If a spam post stays around for 30 minutes that doesn't seem so terrible.  It probably was gone too quickly to even get crawled by search engines.  Staying around for days would be bad.  I will defer to you about this stuff though.  I'm not a real MO'er, just kind of a hanger-on.

Comment: I cannot consider myself to be "real MO'er" for whatever reasonable interpretation of the word. Anyway, I still try to help, for example by removing spam posts when I see them. And the post in the first comment explains some experience with this on other sites in the network. In any case, if we want to continue this discussion in some way, [let's do so in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2019/11/28). (We have digressed from the original topic anyway.)

Answer (score -3):

I would like to suggest to look at the following link which title, subsections and perhaps its body  is related to the subject of conversations of this Meta Mo post. Maybe one can conclude from some subsections of this link  that  we should not  consider an absolut and rigid border between (importance and value of ) questions and answers.

In the title of this link it is included that every answer is an introduction to a new question.
We can imagine a converse situation: A question can implicitly contains a potential answer to another problem.

https://lanouvelletribune.info/2013/09/les-questions-sont-plus-importantes-que-les-reponses-et-chaque-reponse-donne-naissance-a-une-nouvelle-question/

PS: I  just  remember that  a physics professor  told  me his  following  experience:
"one  semester I experienced the  following teaching  method: Every  session, instead of  direct  teaching, I got  examination whose problems and  questions were actually teaching students the  new  materials. By thinking  to my  questions they  spontaneously discover the  materials  of  new  courses"

This physicist  is   a well known translator  of   Philosophical  and  Physical  books.

Comment: I wouldn't say a question contains an answer, so much as it points to or indicates one or more answers.  I think a good question promotes understanding as well if not better than a good answer.  Gerhard "One Reason Why I'm Here" Paseman, 2019.12.01.

Comment: Good questions can be important and useful. I still maintain that the act of **asking interesting questions** is cheaper than the work of **providing decent answers** and indeed there are questions asked on MO which do not actually display sufficient thought or depth

Comment: @GerhardPaseman thank you very much  for your comment. I  agree  to some extent with your modification.

Comment: @Gerhardpaseman  yes I should be more careful so I edit it by adding the word "potential" answer. Thanks again for your interesting comment.